# PHP Function to build a tree starting from specific node

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, tree

I have a table that represents agencies. Each agency may or not have a parent (fk_organismo). The agencies without parent (fk_organismo = NULL) are the root agencies.

[image: table structure]

Could anyone help me with a **php** function (recursive or not) that can build the complete hierarchical tree, and that can also receive an optional parameter: fk_organismo (parent_agency_id). If this parameter is not NULL, the tree should be built starting from this specific agency?

1. **I must show all the agencies in a tree**
2. **Must show a tree of all the children agencies starting from a specific one**

*I also guess I will have to build two (2) separate SQL queries, one for getting all agencies, other for getting all the children from a specific one, but not sure...*

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: http://waliaz.com/modified-pre-ordered-traversal-tree-mptt---explained.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking something like this(Fixed, tested)

```
$conn = new mysqli("hostname","user","password","database");
if($conn->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n",$conn->connect_error);
    exit();
}

function dbToTree(){
//Set up your connection to mysql first
    global $conn;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `database`.`table` WHERE `fk_organismo` IS NULL ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 1000;";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    for($i = 0; $db_array[$i] = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); $i++);

    array_pop($db_array); //The last part of the array is empty, remove it

    foreach($db_array as $row => $columns){
        $db_tree[$columns['nombre']]['info'] = $columns; //Tree root is ID of agency

        $db_tree[$columns['nombre']]['children'] = find_children($columns['id']);
    }
    return $db_tree;
}

function find_children($fk_organismo){
        global $conn;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `database`.`table` WHERE `fk_organismo` = " . $fk_organismo . " ORDER BY id desc";
        //die($sql);
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if(!$result) return NULL;
        for($i = 0; $tmp[$i] = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); $i++);

        array_pop($tmp);
        foreach($tmp as $tmp_row => $tmp_columns){
            $return[$tmp_columns['nombre']]['info'] = $tmp_columns;
            $return[$tmp_columns['nombre']]['children'] = find_children($tmp_columns['id']);
        }
        if(empty($return)) return NULL;
        return $return;
}
```